# How to reduce edge diffraction?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, laser, diffraction

I have a simple setup with a diode laser and an object placed in front of it.
I want to observe the edge's shadow clearly.

However, I get this very annoying effect of diffraction and interference around the edges of the object(see pic below)

**Is there a way to reduce this effect?** Spatial coherence is mandatory for my setup, but spectral/temporal isn't.

The two solutions I've thought of are:
**(a)** using a temporally incoherent source, like an arc lamp (which unfortunately won't be as spatially coherent as a laser) and
**(b)** somehow randomly scrambling the phase through the beam's section

I'm not good with optics though so I don't know if these will work or how to implement them.
Different approaches with regards to the light source are welcome.

[image: edge diffraction razor]

Comment: It is a pity that the diffraction pattern annoys you but it is due to the fact that light is behaving like a wave and therefore is not in the realm of geometrical optics which in theory should give you a sharp edge to the shadow.  If you use a white light source then you may also be frustrated because there will be a visible penumbra unless the source is made very "small" or the incident light is parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diffraction can be greatly reduced by any of several methods. You haven't mentioned the objective of your experiment, so some of these might not be useful.

**First method:** You already suggested the first: reduce the temporal coherence of the source.  For this, you can use an LED rather than a laser, but an LED typically has rather poor spatial coherence.    Alternatively, you can put a rotating diffuser in the system which will reduce both spatial and temporal coherence. To get high spatial coherence from a very bright spatially incoherent source, focus it onto a pinhole. You're then trading brightness for spatial coherence.

**Second method:**  Place a lens between the object and the screen to image the object on the screen.  This will almost entirely eliminate the diffraction "ringing" around the edges of the image.  A zoom lens will allow you to adjust the size of the image.  I'm guessing this might work for you because you've said you need a spatially coherent source, which suggests you just want to obtain a "shadow" that amounts to an enlarged silhouette of the object.

**Third method:** Select your object to have optically "soft" edges rather than abrupt opaque-transparent transitions.  This amounts to *apodization*.  I'm guessing this won't serve your purpose.

Comment: I disagree with 2nd method, or you have omitted something.
I did try using a microscope with laser illumination and the interference noise is all over the image.

The image  pictured was already taken with a lens between the object and the (ccd) screen

Comment: If so, the lens was not positioned correctly to focus the image.  Please see the Thin Lens equation: [http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/lenseq.html]  Of course, if the lens is dirty there will be a lot of diffraction from the dirt.  If the object is a razor blade and you want an image that is a few inches across, you probably need a lens a couple of inches wide.

Comment: It seems like I'll just have to use classical optics (ie, a lens to project the object).  
  
However I'm disappointed that we don't have light sources with high spatial coherence and no temporal coherence. I suppose they would be very useful.

Comment: Actually there are such sources.  For example, a "white light" laser or a supercontinuum laser which emits a nearly continuous broadband spectrum.  However, diffraction fringes form in the shadow even when the light source is temporally incoherent.  If you let sunlight project through a tiny hole into a dark room, and put a straight edge in the beam, the shadow will have diffraction fringes.  See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_light_interferometry].

Comment: @S.McGrew You're right, I was confused, forgetting that a changing phase is equivalent to a broad spectrum emission (with Fourier analysis etc).
However I still don't get why you'd get fringes if you have an arrangement with ie a point source that emits monochromatic light with a different, random phase per unit of angle (ie phase is 35° at dead center, 44° at 1° right, 87° at 2° right etc).
Shouldn't the secondary (diffraction) sources be in sync with the incoming wave, hence cancelling out? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It appears that you're describing a monochromatic source with a static phase shift in each direction.  That would be a very strange light source.  I suspect it is only possible for a spatially extended source, with the rate of variation of static phase vs angular direction dependent on the ratio of the diameter of the source to the wavelength of light.  I think Huygen's principle can be used to prove this, but I haven't done the math.  In other words, I think there can be no such *point* source.

Comment: OK- sketch the wavefront you envision, where the phase varies rapidly with angle around a source.  The wavefront will be irregular.  Use Huygens principle to trace the wavefront backwards toward the source.  You will see that it cannot converge to a point.

Comment: I'd say that an LED has a good spatial coherence, and poor temporal coherence (poorer than a laser), given its microscopic size. Unless it's an array of LEDs in a single package.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce wavelength (blue laser) [so that the diffraction pattern will shrink](https://youtu.be/szGJnpNowqw?t=461)

Answer (score 0):

Vibration of the object may help, you would need to get a time averaged measurement.  Or can you do a mathematical correction based on observing the maxima and using a formula similar to single slit diffraction.